# How to add a shadow to the Widget, without Container -> BoxShadow in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have different places in the App where I can't use `Container` and its `BoxShadow` functionality so I used to use the SimpleShadow widget, to add shadows to the image buttons etc. Everything was okay until I updated the Flutter version from `3.7.0` to `3.13.1`.So the SimpleShadow widget starts to clip shadow with the child bounds.
[image: Shadown Before/After Flutter update]
I can use `Container -> decorations -> boxShadow` for buttons, but this option is not suitable for "icons/images".

[image: Icon with clipped shadow]

I went to the source code and found `Stack` there, so I thought I'd just add `clipBehaviour: Clip.none` and that it, but it didn't help. Here is source code:

```
    Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: <Widget>[
        if (color.alpha != 0)
          Transform.translate(
            offset: offset,
            child: ImageFiltered(
              imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaY: sigma, sigmaX: sigma, tileMode: TileMode.decal),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    width: 0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Opacity(
                  opacity: opacity,
                  child: ColorFiltered(
                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcATop),
                    child: child,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        child,
      ],
    );
```

So I think that `ImageFiltered` or `ColorFiltered` widgets have their own clip functionality inside, which I couldn't find. Also, I can't find in the Google any other ways how add shadow to the PNG Image. For example as `box-shadow` property works in CSS. Any thoughts?